# jQuery slider with range and different background-color

Tags: jquery

I have tried this basic jQuery range slider

```
<script>
$(function() {
$( "#slider" ).slider();
});
</script>
```

html

```
<div id='slider'></div>
```

how to customize range to show different background color and tool tip

Answer (score 0):

```
$( "#slider" ).css("background","red");
$(".ui-slider-range-min").css("background","yellow");
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(function() {
    $( "#slider-range-min" ).slider({
      range: "true",
      value: 37,
      min: 150,
      step:150,
      max: 7000,
      
      slide: function( event, ui ) {
        $( "#amount" ).val( "$" + ui.value );
      }
    });
    $( "#amount" ).val( "$" + $( "#slider-range-min" ).slider( "value" ) );
  });
//You can set multipel values as 
//values: [ 150, 250,1000,3000, 5000, 7000 ],
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<p>
  <label for="amount">Maximum price:</label>
  <input type="text" id="amount" readonly style="border:0; color:#f6931f; font-weight:bold;">
</p>
 
<div id="slider-range-min"></div>
```

Comment: how to add value at bottom of slider and to change the color of slider

Comment: You can do it by **CSS**

Comment: $( "#slider" ).css("background","red");
$(".ui-slider-range-min").css("background","yellow");

Comment: You can even set background image of slider as a ruler(Not very good idea but it works).